# How to view git pull requests in a local server, in command line?

Tags: git, pull-request, pull

I'm running a local git server, and I'm just wondering, is there a way to see all the pull-requests made by developers? Similar to Github or Bitbucket but in command line.

Answer (score 9):

This small configuration change may help you achieve what you want.
 1. Add the following line to your .git/config file 
    `fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` 
 
2. Fetch all pull requests using : `$ git fetch origin`
 
3. To checkout a particular PR run :
`$ git checkout pr/999`

There is a concise guide [here](https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247)

Comment: If you adjusted your config as prescribed by this answer, perhaps with something like `git config --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*"` ...  and then trusted the PR-checkout to naturally setup the new local branch with something like `git checkout pr/999` -- then you will have trouble trying to just `git pull` it again to get PR updates.  The `branch.pr/999.merge` config value will not be correct.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40828472/5844631) for how to address that issue.

Answer (score 7):

`git-request-pull` doesn't send anything. It just prints to your terminal a text, that can be e-mailed to upstream repository owner.

As written in [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull):

> The request, printed to the standard output, begins with the branch description, summarizes the changes and indicates from where they can be pulled.

And in [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/ch5-2.html):

> you can run the `git request-pull` command and email the output to the project maintainer manually

Example from that book:

```
$ git request-pull origin/master myfork
The following changes since commit 1edee6b1d61823a2de3b09c160d7080b8d1b3a40:
  John Smith (1):
        added a new function

are available in the git repository at:

  git://githost/simplegit.git featureA

Jessica Smith (2):
      add limit to log function
      change log output to 30 from 25

 lib/simplegit.rb |   10 +++++++++-
 1 files changed, 9 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 4):

To list all pull requests:

```
git ls-remote origin 'pull/*/head'
```

> acb088927f51e6b48c92eb8bffb5a17723260776  refs/pull/1/head
> cbd690b74526bb621446b169a8e1e1eae85b8901  refs/pull/2/head
> fc39e6b269f187ceeeefc8f71e6eaa95e6618786  refs/pull/3/head
> ...

To show information about specific PR:

```
git ls-remote origin 'pull/3/head' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git show
```

(You can add  `| cat` if the commit output is long).

Output example:

> commit fc39e6b269f187ceeeefc8f71e6eaa95e6618786
> Author: ...
> Date:   ...
>
> add_test_subctl_benchmark
>
> diff --git a/setup_subm.sh b/setup_subm.sh
> index 1fce037..621336b 100755
> ...

Answer (score 3):

All the above answers suggested modifying the .git/config file.
If you don't want to change the git config file to list all the Pull requests you can use the following command

```
git fetch origin +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

Comment: can you describe step-by-step what this does?

Answer (score 3):

There is a new official [Github CLI](https://cli.github.com/) released recently.

Install it with `brew install gh`, and then list Pull Requests with:

```
gh pr list
```

Answer (score 2):

You have lot of tools to view your git server statistics.

[gitinspector](https://github.com/ejwa/gitinspector) for example is one of them. There are lot more where you can see statistics in a nice way.

There is a command for console which allows you to check commits by author. check this,

```
git shortlog -s -n
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this command to see all the pull request made by developers:

```
git shortlog -n
```

after running the command keep pressing enter to log the complete details.