# What is the correct git config for working with GitHub pull requests?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm aware of [How can I check out a GitHub pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567846/how-can-i-checkout-a-github-pull-request/40662243)

While adding `fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` to `.git/config` does allow fetch and checkout, pull actions fail:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/the/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

Fetch and checkout work fine:

```
$ git fetch origin
```

... all good

```
$ git checkout -b "pr-123" origin/pr/123
Branch pr-123 set up to track remote branch pr/123 from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'pr-123'
```

... success, got the code!

But pull fails:

```
$ git pull
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/pr/123' 
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

... failed.

I can specify the ref manually:

```
$ git pull origin refs/pull/123/head
```

and this works. But how can I configure the config file so that:

1. fetch & checkout still work, and
2. subsequent pull actions work without manually specifying the remote ref?

---

I have found that if I edit the config file and change:

```
[branch "pr-123"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/pr/123
```

to:

```
[branch "pr-123"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/pull/123/head  # <-- here is the change
```

... then `git pull` works fine. How can this be achieved without manually editing the config file for every pull request?

Comment: Are you asking how to edit the git config once for all pull requests? That link you posted has the answer, does that not work for you?

Comment: @yBot It does not. Namely, `pull` does not work. I have added the config file bit to the question, maybe there is something wrong there?

Comment: I'm not sure how checking out `origin/pr/123` worked for you, there should be no such ref for PR (maybe you have a remote branch with this name?). Try `refs/remote/origin/pr/123`. When you do fetch, this is what you should see getting fetched.

Comment: @yBot Frankly I don't know why (or why it shouldn't) but it does work. Also, adding `refs/remote/` makes the checkout command fail. Fetch results look like this:  `* [new ref]         refs/pull/123/head  -> origin/pr/123 ` ... I'm tempted to start up a virtual machine and make a screencast :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found a solution, and it's unbelievably simple: Order of the lines with `fetch = +refs...` matters!

I changed:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/the/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

to:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/the/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

(last two lines swapped)

Now everything works (`fetch`, `checkout`, `pull`).

I'm still waiting to see some (un)expected problems with this configuration, but so far so good...

Comment: If anyone encounters a problem with this solution, please comment

Comment: I was having the same problem -- and even today with Git 2.33.1 this solution still works.   I am astounded that this order matters, but it very much does.   Without this, `git checkout pr/1` creates a bad merge entry in config:  `merge = refs/heads/pull/1`.  But with this fix, somehow the same command, `git checkout pr/1` creates `merge = refs/pull/1/head`
With the correct `branch.pr/1.merge` config entry -- everything works.

Answer (score 9):

You've only fetched branches, not pull requests. Add this to your config:

`fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/pulls/origin/pr/*`

After that you can checkout a branch that points to a PR remote ref:

`git checkout -b "pr-123" pulls/origin/pr/123`

Generally, you can check out a ref if you've fetched it from the remote, so look through the `git fetch` command output and find the PR's ref name. That's what you should put in the `checkout` command. You should see something like:

`[new ref]      refs/pull/123/head -> refs/pulls/origin/pr/123`

Note that you can substitute the `pulls` part for any custom prefix. You can now create a branch and point it to `pulls/origin/pr/123`, which is equivalent to `refs/pulls/origin/pr/123` (see [git refspec doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)).

Comment: My bad, you should omit the prefix `refs`, it's implied. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Despite all the upvotes, this answer does not solve my problem. It simply does not work, actually.

Comment: I'm very interested to know why it doesn't work for you. It works fine for me. If someone else can confirm that would be great too.

Answer (score 4):

From the fetch specs is not possible to find unambiguously find that remote reference `refs/remotes/origin/pr/123` tracks `origin:refs/pull/123/head` because `origin:refs/heads/pr/123` is also possible. To help it, you could use different remote name for example:

```
[remote "origin-pr"]
  url = <same as for origin>
  fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin-pr/pr/*
```

Then git checkout with explicit branch name (which should be available in GUIs) would be able to create correct tracking reference:

```
$ git checkout -b pr/123 origin-pr/pr/123

[branch "pr/123"]
 remote = origin-pr
 merge = refs/pull/123/head
```

Though, looks like it is not possible to make simple `git checkout br/123` work:

```
$ git checkout pr/123                         
error: pathspec 'pr/123' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: This answer is a solution. We can configure two remotes: `origin` for regular branches, and `origin-pr` for PRs. It seems to work just fine, as long as the correct remote is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

One correct way is with [hub](https://hub.github.com/)! `:)`

```
$ brew install hub
$ hub checkout https://github.com/github/hub/pull/123

...

$ hub pull
Already up-to-date.
```

It has extra utilities for working with Github pull requests, such as

```
hub pull-request
```

Comment: How does this help the author at all? The question is about the correct git config.

Comment: Does not help, because in the end this git config is used by a GUI (SourceTree). Thanks for the info, though.

Comment: There are [custom actions](https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/02/08/custom-act) in SourceTree which can run arbitrary commands

Comment: To all the downvoters: really?! Yeah, it's not a direct answer to my exact question, but it is quite related, isn't it? It could have been useful in a bit different circumstances. And it may yet be useful to a googler in the future.

Comment: Andy Ray: here have my upvote! I think it was a useful answer! Not exactly what OP wanted but might be useful for someone else.