# VS Code: View git remote changes before pull request?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Hi i new for VScode and for view remote changes on git before pull request is there any way? ,I found Git History extension but which is for local changes only. not compare remote and local files ,Can some one suggest me please.

Answer (score 5):

You can compare branches (including remote tracking ones) with the VSCode plugin [Git Lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens), [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57833947/6309).

But, if you want to compare incoming pull requests, don't forget to [add refs/pull rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40700695/6309), in order to VSCode to fetch said PR, and for you to compare them with your branch.