# Git fetch Pull Requests from Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

I want to fetch, using git, the list of Pull Requests in a repository hosted in Azure DevOps.

[Github has the support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567846/how-can-i-check-out-a-github-pull-request-with-git).
We can just add this to `.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

But when I tried the same method for Azure DevOps, it didn't fetch anything. I also tried `git-pr` from the `git-extras` package.

I am guessing if they have the support, the path might be different from `refs/remotes/origin/pr/`.They have a [REST API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to fetch pull requests, but I couldn't find anything about doing the same using git.

Comment: one way to discover what refs are available on a remote : `git ls-remote <remote or url>`

Comment: @LeGEC, thanks! `git ls-remote` is the solution for any remote.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For Azure DevOps the configuration is slightly different. You can add the following to `.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/pull/*/merge:refs/remotes/origin/pull/*
```

It is also possible to perform an ad-hoc fetch of a pull-request into a local branch without prior configuration like this:

```
git fetch origin refs/pull/$ID/merge:$LOCALBRANCH
```

---

*Example fetch and checkout (with configuration):*

```
$ git fetch origin -v
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 1 objects to send. (18 ms)
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
From ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/aaaa/bbbb/cccc
 = [up to date]      main              -> origin/main
 = [up to date]      test-branch       -> origin/test-branch
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/1/merge -> origin/pull/1
$ git checkout pull/1
Branch 'pull/1' set up to track remote branch 'pull/1' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'pull/1'
```

*Example ad-hoc fetch and checkout (no prior configuration):*

```
$ git fetch origin refs/pull/1/merge:pull/1
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 1 objects to send. (53 ms)
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
From ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/aaaa/bbbb/cccc
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/1/merge -> pull/1
$ git checkout pull/1
Switched to branch 'pull/1'
```

Comment: A note about the config change described above, `git config --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/pull/*/merge:refs/remotes/origin/pull/*"`.  If you follow the first example -- automatically setting up the new local branch with something like `git checkout pull/1` -- you may have just created a broken `branch.pull/1.merge` config value, and you may have trouble trying to just `git pull` it again to get PR updates.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40828472/5844631) for how to address that issue (there 'head' was used, not 'merge' -- so not sure if it fully applies here).

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better to define a new remote with the same url but different fetch config.

```bash
 [remote "pull"]
     url = <same-as-origin>
     fetch = +refs/pull/*/merge:refs/remotes/pull/*
```

You can check out pull requests with:

```bash
git fetch pull
git checkout pull/<pull-request-id>
```

This will avoid the merge conflict that would arise when you are using the same remote with two different fetch configs.

Here's a similar answer with explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40701668/2312300